# JSLint reports “Insecure '^'” on "^&;" from JavaScript: The Good Parts - ignore?

Tags: javascript, regex

[JavaScript: The Good Parts p41](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA41) contains the following regex:

```
/&([^&;]+);/g
```

which is used to find all HTML entities such as `&gt;`. If one validates this code with JSLint it reports

> Insecure '^'

While this is correct strictly speaking, I still believe it's fine to ignore it. Or not?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/&([^&;]+?);/g` ?

Comment: You're going to need a `{1,10}` or something before your regular expression works - at the moment it won't match `&gt;` (but would match `&g;`).

Comment: @RichieHindle No, _rausch is right. It should be lazy match. Besides the question is not about this.

Comment: @rausch, you're right - almost. I forgot a '+'. There is '+' in the code sample in Crockford's book. Ohh, someone just edited my post to fix this, thanks.

Comment: @SalmanA, I _do_ know what JSLint wants to tell me. If I had to rewrite the regex to avoid '^' I'd essentially have to list all characters actually found in HTML entities. Which is impractical in my opinion.

Comment: @MarcelStör In that case see rausch's answer. In fact, it is possible to match HTML entities via better regex.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I realize (in hind sight) this really isn't a good question to ask @SO, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's warning that the regular expression might match more than expected, and it is correct to warn about it; it will match things like this “`&abc def ghi;`” despite them being illegal entity names. On the other hand, it is probably not a serious problem in this case (though it strictly depends on what you do after matching); you can disable it in JSLint easily enough.

A better RE would be:

```
/&(#[0-9]+|#[xX][a-fA-F0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+);/
```

I can't remember what other characters are permitted in entity names, alas.

Answer (score 2):

To offer an answer to the actual question. If you know why it is *insecure* and are okay with it, ignore it. If you are annoyed by JSLint complaining, fix it. ;)

I would consider it *secure enough*.